# $first in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a MongoDB query like

```
// Get scoreboard of challenge
response.aggregate = await ScoreBoardModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { challenge_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.challenge_id) } },
    { $group: { _id: '$user_id', value: { $sum: '$value' } } },
]);
```

Which outputs like

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5b762887b6e3a91c60c01718",
    "value": 4300
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b8b41f10186400163d0df83",
    "value": 6800
  },
  {
    "_id": "5b762590b6e3a91c60c01713",
    "value": 2023
  }
]
```

But i want to perform this query something like below:

```
response.aggregate = await ScoreBoardModel.aggregate([
    { $match: { challenge_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.challenge_id) } },
    { $lookup: {
        from: 'appusers',
        let: { 'user_id': '$user_id' },
        pipeline: [{ $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$_id', '$$user_id' ] } } },],
        as: 'user'
    } },
    { $group: { _id: '$user_id', value: { $sum: '$value' } } },
]);
```

I want to `$lookup` in `appusers` to get details of each `appusers`.
How do i do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use [**`$first`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) aggregation operator to return the first document after applying the [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) stage.

```
ScoreBoardModel.aggregate([
  { "$match": { challenge_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(req.body.challenge_id) } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "appusers",
    "let": { "user_id": "$user_id" },
    "pipeline": [{ "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$user_id" ] } } }],
    "as": "user"
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$user_id",
    "value": { "$sum": "$value" },
    "appusers": { "$first": "$user" },
  }}
])
```

Comment: And then it returns [{"_id":"5b762887b6e3a91c60c01718","value":4300,"appusers":null},{"_id":"5b8b41f10186400163d0df83","value":6800,"appusers":null},{"_id":"5b762590b6e3a91c60c01713","value":2023,"appusers":null}]

Comment: Sorry it's `user` not `appusers`... Check the updated answer

Comment: Yes. It worked!
Thank you Anthony.

There's one more thing i need to ask.
It's returning all the information of appusers. But i only want basic info like and and stuff. How do i project basic info?

Comment: this will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51950121/exclude-fields-in-lookup-aggregation... Just use `$project` inside pipeline...