# MongoDB | How do I merge with an existing value?

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework, lookup

DB is as follows.

collections : Comment

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc4348f8e798ccb030991e8")
    "comment_no" : 143,
    “comment_content” : “test test”
}
```

collections : Post

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc16b068e798ccb03096efa"),
    "post_no" : 48,
    "comment" : [ 
        {
            "comment_no" : 143,
            "comment_group" : 1 // This value will disappear.
        }
    ]
}
```

The query looks like this:

```
db.getCollection('post').aggregate([
{
    $match : {post_no: 48}
    },
    {
        $lookup: {
            from: 'comment'
            localField: 'comment.comment_no',
            foreignField: 'comment_no',
            as: 'comment'
        }
    }
])
```

The results are as follows.

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc16b068e798ccb03096efa"),
    "post_no" : 48,
    "comment" : [ 
        {
            "comment_no" : 143,
            “comment_content” : “test test”
        }
    ]
}
```

Existing data disappears, but I want to merge the value of comment_group.

For example, The result I want is..

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5bc16b068e798ccb03096efa"),
    "post_no" : 48,
    "comment" : [ 
        {
            "comment_no" : 143,
            “comment_content” : “test test”,
            "comment_group" : 1 // Here!! I want to use this value.
        }
    ]
}
```

Can I make a query so that values are merged into comment_no?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try below aggregation

You need to first [**`$unwind`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) the `comment` array to match with the exact `comment_no` and then [**`$group`**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) to rollback again into its original form

```
db.getCollection("post").aggregate([
  { "$match": { "post_no": 48 }},
  { "$unwind": "$comment" },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": "comment"
    "localField": "comment.comment_no",
    "foreignField": "comment_no",
    "as": "comment.comment_content"
  }},
  { "$unwind": "$comment.comment_content" },
  { "$addFields": {
    "comment": {
      "$mergeObjects": ["$comment", "$comment.comment_content"]
    }
  }},
  { "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
    "comment": { "$push": "$comment" }
  }}
])
```

Comment: Thank you!! There is actually a lot of fields in the comment collection.
Is there a way to combine fields in addition to 'addfields' ?

Comment: Very nice!!! Thank you very much!! It really helped me a lot. But there are actually many fields in the 'Post' collection. Why do all of the values in the 'Post collection' disappear?

Comment: Use  `$first` for other fields in `$group` stage. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52215916/first-in-mongodb/52216320#52216320

Comment: @flyhigh Did you get me?

Comment: @Anthony_Winzlet 
{ "$group": {
    "_id": "$_id",
     ** "post_no": { "$first": "$post_no" }, **
    "comment": { "$push": "$comment" }
  }}

is it right? 
I wish it would be simple and dynamic, but I think I should use this method.
Thank you!!!

Answer (score 0):

You can get what you want like this:

```
db.post.aggregate([
{
    $match : { post_no: 48 }
}, {
    $unwind: '$comment' // flatten 'comment' array into sub-documents
}, {
    $lookup: {
        from: 'comment',
        let: {
            'comment': '$comment', // keep a reference to the 'comment' sub-document
        },
        pipeline: [{
            $match: { $expr: { $eq: [ '$comment_no', '$$comment.comment_no' ] } } // perform the join
        }, {
            $replaceRoot: { "newRoot": { $mergeObjects: [ '$$comment', '$$ROOT' ] } } // merge the found object with the original content of 'comment'
        }],
        as: 'comment'
    }
}, {
    $group: { // restore the original structure
        _id: '$_id',
        'comment': { $push: { $arrayElemAt: [ '$comment', 0 ] }  }
    }
}])
```

Comment: This method returns the result is object in array. It helped. Thank you.

comment (Array) - Array - Object